# Getting 'Not found' after deploying my react web application

Tags: reactjs, deployment, dirname

I'm trying to deploy my React application on Vercel. After deployment I'm getting 'NOT FOUND' when i'm trying to visit the link. Screen shot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPH36.jpg)

This is my **index.js** file code:

```
// express acts as a server
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import Connection from "./database/db.js";
import DefaultData from "./default.js";
import router from "./routes/route.js";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { v4 as uuid} from "uuid";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

// intializing

// creating server
// three arguments - port, callback function

const app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", router);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

Connection();

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

console.log(__dirname);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))

  app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running successfully on Port ${PORT}`)
);

// DefaultData();
```

I think this code is not able to resolve dirname. Please help me out..

Comment: When you are running it, are you certain the `NODE_ENV` env var has been set to `production` in your environment? The error is because it cant find a route handler. So that `if` block is suspicious.

Comment: Still the same error... This is the file code. import { MONGO_URI } from "./prod.js";

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? MONGO_URI : MONGO_URI;

export default config;